# How to add --force flag to NPM in Azure Pipeline

Tags: angular, npm, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-static-web-app

I've set up an Azure Static Web App, and I've got an Angular 13 web app that I'd like to publish to it. So, I push my git commit to Azure DevOps, and the Azure Pipeline in DevOps (that was automatically created when I created the Static Web App in Azure Portal) gets triggered. So far so good. However, when the pipeline tries to build the app (NPM), it's giving an error. I know that if I force the build, the web app works anyway, and as a temporary solution, this is what I'd like to do. I've been fiddling with the YAML of the Azure Pipeline to try and add the --force flag, but after an entire day, I still cannot get it to work. This is the YAML of the Azure Pipeline:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-purple-grass-0e645d303-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_PURPLE_GRASS_0E645D303)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

If anyone could point to where I can add the --force flag, I'd be immensely appreciative!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add **--force** flag, you can add the custom NPM build command to the field: **app_build_command** and **api_build_command**.

For example:

```
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/'
      api_location: 'api'
      app_build_command: 'npm install --force'
      output_location: ''
      api_build_command: 'npm install --force'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Build configuration for Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions)

Answer (score 0):

trigger:

- develop

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- checkout: self
  submodules: true
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
  app_build_command: node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c develop --build-optimizer
  app_location: '/'
  api_location: 'api'
  output_location: 'dist'
  **env:**
  azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
  **NPM_CONFIG_FORCE: true** 
  **NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS: true**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this workflow setting in GitHub actions ended up working

```
      - name: Build And Deploy
    uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    with:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN}}
      repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      action: "upload"
      app_location: ${{ env.APP_LOCATION }}
      api_location: ${{ env.API_LOCATION }}
      output_location: ${{ env.OUTPUT_LOCATION }}
    env:
      NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS: true
```

The last line was the change that made it work

```
    env:
  NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS: true
```

Used an Azure static web app to deploy the hybrid next.js app

Also, refer to this thread:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1299561/unable-to-run-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-in-azur